# Optimizing Azure Analysis Services processing on Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-analysis-services, azure-synapse

I have a massive model with billions of records within Synapse Analytics that needs to be loaded into Azure Analysis Services. At present we have the tables partitioned by month, datatypes and joins are perfect and we have reduced the tables to ONLY the columns we need. We have scaled Synapse to DWU 5000c and Azure Analysis Services to S9v2 (the max setting). Given above it still takes hours and hours to process full for the first load with up to 64 partitions running in parallel given concurrency in Synapse.

*I am curious, is there a setting that can enable a 'mass bulk import process full' that I am missing at this point?*

For example here: https://www.businessintelligenceinfo.com/business-intelligence/self-service-bi/building-an-azure-analysis-services-model-on-top-of-azure-blob-storage-part-3, he is loading differently as from storage blobs and was able to load 1 TB by changing the config as: ReadBlobData(Source, ““, 1, 50). *If there is any similar config for Synapse to Analysis Services?*

Comment: Exactly how long does a full process take currently? What is your expectation exactly? What is the current bottleneck? Is there one large fact table which takes the bulk of the time? Is a full process really that important or is incremental processing more important? How long does incremental processing take?

Comment: Incremental deftly more important, we haven't run it all the way through because our management studio keeps losing connection due to stay at home wifi (trying to get service principal),  I am just curious if there is a setting I missing in a configuration file for super large models